# Как получить содержание из переменной в json C#?

Tags: c#, json

Использую (Newtonsoft.Json)

У меня есть класс Delo в котором описан Json Файл

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestArea
{
    public class Delo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Podpis { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

и файл json

```
{"Name":"vasya","Podpis":"rar","Number":0}
```

При нажатии кнопки, я хочу вывести содержание NAME, каким образом это можно реализовать?
(Пробывал так, но не знаю почему не работает)

```
string temp1 = File.ReadAllText("info.json");
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Delo>(temp1);
// просто в обращении к temp1. (Name не существует), а в классе он есть.
```

Comment: Попробуйте записать считанную информацию с файла в `List<Delo>`, затем с помощью `foreach` выводить ваше имя

Comment: temp1 является тем же json"ом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать такой метод, в котором считаете данные с файла:

```
public static List<Delo> ReadFile(string path)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Delo>>(json);
        }
```

Затем метод, в котором их будете выводить:

```
public static void PrintInfo(List<Delo> elements)
        {
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{element.Name}");
            }
        }
```

Как-то так, без файла не могу запустить, попробовать, поэтому, попробуйте.